# Pretty print code to PDF

Tags: ruby, pretty-print

I'm searching for a tool that will take a source directory and produce a single PDF containing the source code, preferably with syntax highlighting.

I would like to read the PDF on my phone, in order to get familiar with a code-base, or just to see what I can learn by reading a lot of code. I will most often be reading Ruby.

I would prefer if the tool ran on Linux. I don't mind paying for a tool if it is particularly good.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF is no good for reflowing. You might like a html based solution better.

And in reading existing code, a lineair model is no good. You need to jump from one file to the other. A hypertext model with history would probably work best on the limited screen estate of a phone. It should borrow some features of the smalltalk IDEs (jump to senders, implementors).

For the UI, take a look at [clamato](http://clamato.net)

Comment: +1 Good point re reflow. I'll just have to figure out how to open HTML docs on my phone - which *should* be easier than opening PDF you might think.

Comment: [Highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.html) is great for converting source code to HTML. It has support for a great deal of languages, output formats, and themes. I've used Highlight to output code into HTML and view them from Good Reader on my iOS device.

Answer (score 3):

You could wipe something up yourself with [Prawn](http://wiki.github.com/sandal/prawn/) and [Ultraviolet](http://ultraviolet.rubyforge.org/).

Answer (score 1):

[GNU source-highlight](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/source-highlight.html#Introduction) supports many languages and can output LaTeX in particular that can be converted to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

The SciTE editor can export the currently edited file (with syntax highlighting) to PDF (and HTML, RTF, LaTeX and XML).

Alas, it doesn't have batch conversion capability, but IIRC somebody made a batch tool out of this code base.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is very late, but I wanted to do the same thing, except I wanted it for my tablet, which is a Galaxy Note 10.1 with a Wacom digitizer that I can use to annotate code. I found that one good solution is to use Doxygen to generate a PDF which will have hyperlinks and everything you would want in a PDF. For my use case, I would pair it with EzPDF on Android to annotate the code. This was also for the purpose of learning a new codebase. In the end I ended up not using the generated PDF but it was pretty usable.